# Problems with random password verification

Tags: php, random, zend-framework2, bcrypt

I am facing a problem that's literally driving me nuts. Following scenario is given:

- Application A - Manages the users

  - pw created using Bcrypt(), cost 14
- Application B - fetches the User-Data and stores it inside it's local db

  - pw verified through bcrypt(), cost 14

Bcrypt implementation via [`Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Crypt/Password/Bcrypt.php)

So, whenever I create a fixed password on App A, synchronize them, authentication on App B works.

However, whenever I create a **random** password on App A, synchronize them, authentication on App B just won't work.

I pass the password created through a session to a front-end after a redirect.

```
$password = (string) rand(2938, 9578);
//$password = '12345678';

$bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
$bcrypt->setCost(14);
$entity->setPassword($bcrypt->create($password));

$entityService->save($entity);

$this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('MpuServerUser')->addSuccessMessage(
    "Benutzer-PIN erfolgreich erneuert. PIN: {$password}"
);
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('mpuserveruser');
```

As you can see that's the part that I'm facing troubles with. Whenever I create a new password for a User with a given string `'123456'`, there are no problems, whatsoever.

But when I use the uncommented part `$password = (string) rand(2938, 9578);` the password I'm getting on my front-end won't authenticate.

There's no differences between trying with `rand()` or `mt_rand()`. Anyone any idea what the heck is going on here? ^^

**Update** - apparently only passwords that are of 6 chars or longer do work. Even if I set a predefined password of only 4 letters, it won't work.

Comment: Only difference is apart from the length(which shouldn't matter) is that `$password` is random or not, for some reason that i cant see the call to this code may happen twice, to test you should store the value of the rand in a file after it was set. so its the password you think it is. Cant see any other reason it wouldn't match what you expect

Comment: @LozCherone storing the password in a temporal file is actually a good idea, gotta try that one. I'm really losing myself here :D

Comment: @LozCherone while trying your approach it became apparent that somehow this has to do with the length of the password. Only passwords 6 chars or longer work at all. This could be a ZF2 Implementation thingy, i'll have to dig deeper into this! Your idea was good tho!

Comment: I create passwords the same way as you and I have no problems with the lengths. I use **\Zend\Math\Rand** class instead of native php **rand**, but I've tested your exact code and it works for me. I'm not an expert at all with BCrypt, but once I had a problem called backwards compatibility. I wasn't able to validate users when php version was 5.3.3. Maybe is something like that...

Comment: @lluisaznar This is a very interesting point. I'm actually running 5.3.3 in here... Could you provide your testcode please? Trying to set up a test and wanna make sure we are pretty much identical :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my piece of code:

```
(...)

//I USE ZfcUserAdmin MODULE
if ( $this->getOptions()->getCreateUserAutoPassword() ) {
    //HERE'S WHERE I'VE TRIED
    //\Zend\Math\Rand::getInteger( 2938, 9578 ); --> OK
    //rand( 2938, 9578 ); --> OK
    $rand = \Zend\Math\Rand::getString( 8 );
    $user->setPassword( $rand );
}

$uncrypted_password = $user->getPassword();

$bcrypt = new Bcrypt;

//PASSWORD COST IS SET TO 14, LIKE YOU
$bcrypt->setCost( $userOptions->getPasswordCost() );
$user->setPassword( $bcrypt->create( $uncrypted_password ) );

(...)
```

The only difference between your solution and mine, is that you redirect and store the password in the session, while I just send an email to the user with the generated password. If I use the new credentials in the email, I can login without problems. Anyway, I think that's not the problem, I suppose it should be something in the **BCrypt** class.

Comment: There's a couple of version_compare() inside Zend\Math and Zend\Crypt. It will be a version specific problem and officially ZF2 by now requires 5.3.23, so there will be no support i suppose. Thanks though for figuring this one out! I wouldn't ever have thought about the php version at all.